# Найти дубликаты в списке

Tags: python

в xclass содержится это:

```
['520025768', '2577960494', '2735408045', '2531854391', '1812814302', '520028244', '1934445778', '2960964943', '2960959302', '1988115969', '2735423107', '1225722045', '2735394070', '3509486944', '1310002360', '937243470', '1310002360', '2220097028', '2531854391', '2531867518', '2960964943', '2076466877', '1703089087', '3220794861', '360454763', '2531853641', '2220015175', '2531853641', '2220052485', '2220052485', '720288675', '360454763', '1703054598', '1309991125', '720276916', '310779460', '2076481798', '310777916', '1812825818', '2735394085', '3220802556', '1011934629', '3220793842', '2076481798', '1812818424', '1703265921', '3035577699', '506858548', '1011934443', '310778159', '1812815327', '2531854572', '992089234', '3220961516', '520025768', '2577960494', '2735408045', '2531854391', '1812814302', '520028244', '1934445778', '2960964943', '2960959302', '1988115969', '2735423107', '1225722045', '2735394070', '3509486944', '1310002360', '937243470', '1310002360', '2220097028', '2531854391', '2531867518', '2960964943', '2076466877', '1703089087', '3220794861', '360454763', '2531853641', '2220015175', '2531853641', '2220052485', '2220052485', '720288675', '360454763', '1703054598', '1309991125', '720276916', '310779460', '2076481798', '310777916', '1812825818', '2735394085', '3220802556', '1011934629', '3220793842', '2076481798', '1812818424', '1703265921', '3035577699', '506858548', '1011934443', '310778159', '1812815327', '2531854572', '992089234', '3220961516', '3113369241', '1011936504', '1011934386', '520025768', '2577960494', '2735408045', '2531854391', '1812814302', '520028244', '1934445778', '2960964943', '2960959302', '1988115969', '2735423107', '1225722045', '2735394070', '3509486944', '1310002360', '937243470', '1310002360', '2220097028', '2531854391', '2531867518', '2960964943', '2076466877', '1703089087', '3220794861', '360454763', '2531853641', '2220015175', '2531853641', '2220052485', '2220052485', '720288675', '360454763', '1703054598', '1309991125', '720276916', '310779460', '2076481798', '310777916', '1812825818', '2735394085', '3220802556', '1011934629', '3220793842', '2076481798', '1812818424', '1703265921', '3035577699', '506858548', '1011934443', '310778159', '1812815327', '2531854572', '992089234', '3220961516']
```

Если тут есть дубликаты,необходимо вывести это число.Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Какое число? Число дубликатов? Или строку, приведённую к типу `int`, у которой есть дубликат? А что если дубликатов несколько?

Comment: Вывести число которое повторяется,хоть 2 раза хоть 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Пример:***

```py
from collections import Counter


li = ['520025768', '2577960494', '2735408045', '2531854391', '1812814302', '520028244', '1934445778', '2960964943', '2960959302', '1988115969', '2735423107', '1225722045', '2735394070', '3509486944', '1310002360', '937243470', '1310002360', '2220097028', '2531854391', '2531867518', '2960964943', '2076466877', '1703089087', '3220794861', '360454763', '2531853641', '2220015175', '2531853641', '2220052485', '2220052485', '720288675', '360454763', '1703054598', '1309991125', '720276916', '310779460', '2076481798', '310777916', '1812825818', '2735394085', '3220802556', '1011934629', '3220793842', '2076481798', '1812818424', '1703265921', '3035577699', '506858548', '1011934443', '310778159', '1812815327', '2531854572', '992089234', '3220961516', '520025768', '2577960494', '2735408045', '2531854391', '1812814302', '520028244', '1934445778', '2960964943', '2960959302', '1988115969', '2735423107', '1225722045', '2735394070', '3509486944', '1310002360', '937243470', '1310002360', '2220097028', '2531854391', '2531867518', '2960964943', '2076466877', '1703089087', '3220794861', '360454763', '2531853641', '2220015175', '2531853641', '2220052485', '2220052485', '720288675', '360454763', '1703054598', '1309991125', '720276916', '310779460', '2076481798', '310777916', '1812825818', '2735394085', '3220802556', '1011934629', '3220793842', '2076481798', '1812818424', '1703265921', '3035577699', '506858548', '1011934443', '310778159', '1812815327', '2531854572', '992089234', '3220961516', '3113369241', '1011936504', '1011934386', '520025768', '2577960494', '2735408045', '2531854391', '1812814302', '520028244', '1934445778', '2960964943', '2960959302', '1988115969', '2735423107', '1225722045', '2735394070', '3509486944', '1310002360', '937243470', '1310002360', '2220097028', '2531854391', '2531867518', '2960964943', '2076466877', '1703089087', '3220794861', '360454763', '2531853641', '2220015175', '2531853641', '2220052485', '2220052485', '720288675', '360454763', '1703054598', '1309991125', '720276916', '310779460', '2076481798', '310777916', '1812825818', '2735394085', '3220802556', '1011934629', '3220793842', '2076481798', '1812818424', '1703265921', '3035577699', '506858548', '1011934443', '310778159', '1812815327', '2531854572', '992089234', '3220961516']

duplicates = [int(k) for k, v in Counter(li).items() if v > 1]
print(duplicates)
```

***stdout:***

```py
[520025768, 2577960494, 2735408045, 2531854391, 1812814302, 520028244, 1934445778, 2960964943, 2960959302, 1988115969, 2735423107, 1225722045, 2735394070, 3509486944, 1310002360, 937243470, 2220097028, 2531867518, 2076466877, 1703089087, 3220794861, 360454763, 2531853641, 2220015175, 2220052485, 720288675, 1703054598, 1309991125, 720276916, 310779460, 2076481798, 310777916, 1812825818, 2735394085, 3220802556, 1011934629, 3220793842, 1812818424, 1703265921, 3035577699, 506858548, 1011934443, 310778159, 1812815327, 2531854572, 992089234, 3220961516]
```

Comment: Тут выводится весь список,надо только то,что повторяется

Comment: @artemso72 Вообще то выводится только то, что повторяется. Проверьте, пожалуйста, свои доводы. Как минимум длины списков различны. В основном списке `165` элементов, повторяется из них `47`.

Comment: Да,заметил сори